# HTML character reading in an associative array

Tags: php, foreach, associative-array

$student[1]=" Marks";

$student["Marks"]=56;

Does PHP not consider HTML break line as a part of the string,since it is accepting value for the same "Marks"?

```
$student[0]="Subject";
$student[1]=" Marks<br>";

$student["Subject"]="English ";
$student["Marks"]=56;//shouldn't it be Marks<br>
foreach($student as $item)
echo $item;
```

Subject Marks
English 56

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking..? To PHP, the `<br />` tag is just part of the string - its just text. It's when its rendered as HTML that its printed as a newline. To get a newline in PHP, use the string `"\n"`

Comment: Why not using a **table**?

Comment: Hi Qirel,kindly go thru the editted part in line 4(added comment for better understanding)?

Comment: Why should it be that..? That's not how PHP works.